Confusion about sign conventions used in the Doppler formula
Wikipedia gives the Doppler formula as:

$ f = \left( \frac{c \pm v_r}{c \pm v_s} \right) f_0 $
c is the propagation speed of waves in the medium.
$v_r$ is the
speed of the receiver relative to the medium, added to c if the
receiver is moving towards the source.
$v_s$ is the speed of the
source relative to the medium, added to c if the source is moving away
from the receiver.

I am having great difficulty trying to derive the following formula from the Doppler formula, for the relative velocity of an object when a source wave is reflected off it as in police radar: $\Delta v =  \frac{\Delta f}{f_0 } \frac{c}{2}$ . Either this is an approximation or I am misunderstanding something very basic about the Doppler formula. My main confusion is about the signs assigned to the velocities. I find the statement "$v_r$: Speed of the receiver relative to the medium, added to c if the receiver is moving towards the source." ambiguous.
For example if the source is on the left of the receiver and is moving to the right at 20 m/s and the receiver is moving to the right at 30 m/s, then technically the source is moving away from the receiver, because the gap between them is getting larger. Should I base the sign on whether or not the gap between them is increasing or not? If anyone has a clean derivation of the relative velocity calculated from the reflected signal frequency  that would help clarify my understanding too.

The Talk-page of that Wikipedia article has a section (link) about the sign conventions of several physics books. Until 2019 the article used the convention from Sears&Zemansky, University Physics, assuming a 1 dimensional coordinate system aligned with the line from receiver to source:
$f = \left( \frac{c + v_r}{c + v_s} \right) f_0$, where the positive direction for $v_r$ and $v_s$ is from receiver towards source.
In 2019 a wikipedia editor changed the formula and its description into its current incomprehensible form.
Alternatively, the general 3 dimensional vector form without a specific coordinate system is
$f = \left( \frac{c+\vec{v}_{r}\cdot \vec{e}_{rs}}{c+\vec{v}_{s}\cdot \vec{e}_{rs}} \right) f_0$

Thanks @jkien. I found your answer helpful. I'm glad I am not the only one that finds the sign conventions a bit confusing¡
